# . Why isn't this string rendered in multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, multiline, template-literals

This code is not being rendered in multiple lines even though I have used JavaScript template literals. Why is it so?

```
document.write(`Today is: ${day} 
             The time now is: ${hours} : ${minutes} hrs 
             The year is: ${year}`);
```

Comment: The document is interpreted as HTML. Newlines in HTML are functionally equivalent to spaces.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing a new line character. or a `<br>`
The break is for html line breaks. add one or two to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. the line break <br> worked but the new line character \n didn't work. Is there an explanation behind it?

Answer (score -1):

use newline character which is `\n` or `<br/>`  tag